# Working with data read from a QR code

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, qr-code

I am attempting to to build an IOS app that will let me input school subjects into a series of text boxes. All of the inputted subjects will go into array; of which I will make a string from. I will then use the string to create a QR code containing the subject list... (well that's the plan anyway!).

Here is the code I am currently using to create the string that I will use to create the QR code:
   //Outlets

```
@IBOutlet var moduleOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var moduleTwo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var moduleThree: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var moduleFour: UITextField!


//Actions

@IBAction func goButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let subjectOne = moduleOne.text!
    let subjectTwo = moduleTwo.text!
    let subjectThree = moduleThree.text!
    let subjectFour = moduleFour.text!

    let newArray: [String] = ["\(subjectOne)", "\(subjectTwo)", " (subjectThree)", "\(subjectFour)"]

    let arrayString = newArray.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    //print(arrayString)

}
```

My aim is to then be able to scan the QR code and place each of the previously inputted subjects into their respective label... this is where I am stuck!

Is it possible to read data from a QR code and then work with specific parts? i.e. If I have stated "Subject One" as being "Maths" can I then ensure that "Maths" goes into my "Subject One" label once I read the QR code? Basically is it possible to look for specific data within the QR code?

Apologies if I haven't been very clear, It's quite a difficult one to explain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely! What you have to do is to specify a kind of "protocol" (not a swift `protocol` but a set of "rules").

What you've done now is just combined the values into a string, separated by a space. This comes with some limitations:

- If you want to introduce a new field, you will have to append it to the end of the string (otherwise you'll have to change a larger portion of your implementation to account for the new value + all your old QR-codes will stop working).
- If one or more of the fields are empty, you'd be left with two spaces in the middle of the string. Depending on your parser, this could result in errors where values are offset in the wrong way.
- You are dependent on the values coming in a certain order when you parse it.

I instead suggest you take some inspiration from URLs instead. Consider the following example:

```
let qrInput = "subjectOne=maths&subjectTwo=music&fall="
let parsed: [String:String] = qrInput.componentsSeparatedByString("&").reduce([:], combine: { (dict, keyValue) in
    var dict = dict
    let components = keyValue.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
    if components.count > 1 {
        dict[components[0]] = components[1]
    }
    return dict
})
```

The example will return a dictionary like: `["subjectTwo": "music", "subjectOne": "maths", "fall": ""]`

This solution is much safer. Simply do `moduleOne.text = dict["subjectTwo"]` or something to populate your UI upon a scan.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think I understand what you mean, (I will need to do some more research on dictionaries!) So when I eventually scan the generated QR code I can just look for "subjectTwo" and work with the data contained in this?

Comment: Thats the idea, yes ;)